# Can not call Mvc Controller Action from AngularJs Controller with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to call my Mvc Controller Action from Angularjs controller $http.get(). Please provide some solution.

**Controller Action :**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public string CallMe(int number,string name)
 {
     return "Welcome " + name +" to Angular Js " + number + " times.";
 }
```

**Angular JS Controller**

```
 app.controller("StoreController", ["$http", function ($http) {        
    $http.get("/Home/CallMe", { number: 4, name: "angular"     }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (error) {           
        console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

Also, Could anyone please specify related material for learning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the details of error that you are getting.

Comment: @user3036342 Thanks.. But I have already googled it. it's my second day with the same problem.

Comment: @Pramod Karandikar  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'number' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String CallMe(Int32, System.String)' in 'AngularJsdemo.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using [$http#get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) method.

```
get(url, [config]);
```

---

```
 Param    Type     Details
 url      string   Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request

 config   Object   Optional configuration object
(optional)
```

For passing parameters `angular.http` provides an option for it `params`

```
$http({
   url: "/Home/CallMe", 
   method: "GET",
   params: {number: 4, name: "angular"}
});
```

Comment: Thank you..  That's what i was looking for. Is there any other way to achieve that apart from #http#get?

Comment: @AjayVerma: You are welcome. Yes you can use `POST` method as well. Just need to change from  method to post and  from `params`  to `data` and you are done. I don't know `C#`

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the `get` method with `post` parameters. `get` only takes a URL parameter, and an optional config one. 
Take a look here at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get).

Try to append your parameters to the URL:

```
 app.controller("StoreController", ["$http", function ($http) {        
    $http.get("/Home/CallMe?number=4&name=angular").success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (error) {           
        console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: It worked. But that again arises a few question: 1. What if I want to send multiple data to the controller? 2. If it is Post; again if  single parameter is required in Mvc Controller (with string name only). Mvc Controller get called with null value. How? What happened to [HttpGet]? e.g. `public string CallMe(string name){}`

Comment: @AjayVerma 1) Multiple data should either be still like this, or wrapped in a class and used in a post request. 2) string especially causes some kind of a problem in posts for some reason. You can either wrap it in a class, or you can try to use `public string CallMe([FromBody] string name)` if you're using WebAPI, that sometimes work