# calling webservice from angularjs mvc-5

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am calling my web service from angularjs

this is my code

```
$http.get('loginservice.asmx/validatelogin', {
                params: {
                    username: $scope.txtlogin,
                    password: $scope.txtpass
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                alert('login success');
            })
```

this is my path when i drag and drop the web service

```
<a href="~/loginservice.asmx">~/loginservice.asmx</a>
```

but when i click on login button

I am getting error and this is how my path look like

```
/login/~/loginservice.asmx/validatelogin?password=123&username=minesh
```

the error is (the resource file cannot be found)

my web service

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TaskManager.App_Code;

namespace MVC5TMS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for loginservice
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class loginservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        DbFunction dbf = new DbFunction();
        Crypto cry = new Crypto();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet =true)]
        public void validatelogin(string username, string password)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", cry.Encrypt(password));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prompt", "SELECT");

            SqlDataReader reader = dbf.ExecuteSP_Reader("User_SIDU", cmd);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Context.Response.Write("success");
                reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Context.Response.Write("fail");
                reader.Close();
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing a relative path in `$http.get` from a page that has `/login/` therefore the two paths get concatenated into `/login/~/loginservice.asmx/validatelogin?password=123&username=minesh` while the correct path seems to be `/loginservice.asmx/validatelogin`

Try using a path starting with `/` in the request.

`$http.get('/loginservice.asmx/validatelogin',...)`

That should result in a correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using params, please use like this:

```
$http({
   url: "/Home/CallMe", 
   method: "GET",
   params: {number: 4, name: "angular"}
});
```

For more details please look this answer [Can not call Mvc Controller Action from AngularJs Controller with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166349/can-not-call-mvc-controller-action-from-angularjs-controller-with-parameters)

There are few modifications you can go with

1. Uncomment `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` because it indicates that a Web service can be invoked from script. Please refer [ScriptService documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. try adding: 
   `<system.web>
     <webServices>
       <protocols>
         <add name="HttpGet"/>
       </protocols>
     </webServices>
   </system.web>`

For more details, please see this video [Consuming ASP NET Web Service in AngularJS using $http](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXbu82N0fQU&index=17&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl)